# checkbox not passing parameter when unchecked in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using checkbox in my application to pass one value in spring .When i checked it it is working fine but the problem lying when I unchecked it.It shows error -

**WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Required String parameter 'isFl' is not present**

here isFl is the name of checkbox which I need to pass.I search lot and got many answer applied in my program but haven't got desired result.

If anyone knowing the answer please help thanks in advance.

controller program

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadPost(@RequestParam String fileName, @Validated Template template,
                               @Validated TemplateBean templateBean,
                              @RequestParam MultipartFile file, 
      HttpServletRequest request,**@RequestParam String isFl**) throws Exception
      {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("upload");


        if(isFl!=null){
            addTemplate.setFl(Integer.parseInt(isFl));
        }
        else{
            addTemplate.setFl(0);//false value
        }
```

**jsp file**

```
 <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" **name="isFl"** value="1" >Facility letter
```

there is lot more things but i have only uploaded relevent to my question

Comment: You might want to include the relevant code here.

Comment: ok please wait i am uploading

Comment: That has nothing to do with spring but on how the checkbox works. When not checked there will be no value (check the HTML spec for this). Instead of using a plain tag use the spring `checkbox` tag and make it part of your template bean.

Comment: that also result in same thing i tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use required = false
@RequestParam(value = "isFl", required = false) String isFl

Comment: Please explain your answer don't just respond with bare-code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden input with prefix '_' added to the same name as below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_isFl" value="on" >
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like that `...HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam Boolean isFl)` because checkbox is a boolean value.

> **Required** and **String** parameter 'isFl' is not present

But the parameter `Boolean isFl` is present in your form

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my answer related to checkboxes value not being sent when it's unchecked and its value is bound to a non-boolean field (i.e., String) since this question shows as a top result.

In Spring's WebDataBinder, it has a field marker described as `DEFAULT_FIELD_DEFAULT_PREFIX`. This is described in Spring's [WebDataBinder API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html#DEFAULT_FIELD_DEFAULT_PREFIX).

Basically, what it does is that it sends a default value when a certain checkbox is unchecked. This is particularly useful when a checkbox is bound to a non-boolean field (i.e., String)

The default field default prefix in Spring is an exclamation mark **(!)**.

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="isFl" value="1" >Facility letter
<input type="hidden" name="!isFl" value="0" />
```

The codes above will send a value of **"1"** if the checkbox is ticked (or checked). Otherwise, it will send **"0"** (value of hidden input item).

P.S.